# Doubt about of isometries representation in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

I reading the following Theorem in (Do carmo, Riemannian Geometry, Chaprter VIII, Section 5.)

> Theorem 1. (Loiuville): Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $n\geq 3$, be a conformal trasnformation a open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $f$ is the restriction to $U$ of a composition of isometries, dilations or inversions, at most one of each.

On the other hand I finded the following result:

> Theorem 2. If $F$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then there exist a unique translation $T$ and a unique orthogonal transformation $C$ such that $F=TC$.

Here, we have

> Definition(Conformal map). $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is conformal, if, and only if for all $p\in U$ and for all pairs of vectors $v_{1},v_{2} \in p$ is true that:
> $$\langle df_{p}(v_{1}), df_{p}(v_{2})\rangle\leq\lambda^{2}(p) \langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle, \hspace{4mm}\lambda\neq0$$

and

> Definition(Isometry). A  a diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is isometry, if, and only if  for all $p\in U$ and for all pairs of vectors $v_{1},v_{2} \in T_{p}\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is true that:
> $$\langle df_{p}(v_{1}), df_{p}(v_{2})\rangle = \langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle_{p}, $$

My doubt are the following:

1. I think that as a particular case of conformal map we have the isometries, only put $\lambda(p)=1$, but I don't sure abuout this affirmation since in the conformal map we consider only vectors in $p$. Is true this affirmation?
2. If the  affirmation (1) above is true, as From the Theorem 2. we have $F=TC$, and from Theorem 1. have other "face" for $f$. I understand that $C$ is an isometry, so $T$ form Theorem $2$  must be a inversion or a dilatation, but I belive that it isn't a dilatation, so it must be a inversion. does my idea work?
3. Why is the importance of the isometries? My professor talked about of congruence of trianglues, but I don't understand the importance of this reason. In other site I finded: More generally, Euclidean geometry can be defined as the totality of concepts that are preserved by isometries of Euclidean space, so I kept thinking in the importance of Isometries and this definition of Euclidean geoemtry.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to assume in Theorem 1 that $U$ is connected. Your definition of a conformal map is wrong.  I also could not figure out what are you asking in 1. Does an "affirmation" mean a "proof?" If so, a proof of what? Liouville's theorem is hard and does not have a 1-paragraph proof.

Comment: Hi @Moise Kohan. Thanks for the obsservations.  why the definition of conformal map is wrong? when said affirmation I meant that I have doubts about this idea:  "I think that as a particular case of conformal map we have the isometries, only put $\lambda(p)=1$.

Comment: It is wrong (your definition) because you wrote inequality when it should be an equation. Your writing is very unclear,  but once you require $\lambda(p)=1$ for all $p$, then the a smooth map of $R^n$ is a $\lambda$-conformal if and only if it preserves the Euclidean metric tensor. From this it follows that the map is a composition of a translation and an orthogonal transformation (holds for all $n\ge 2$): It is a theorem, not very difficult one. Of course, if you've never heard of this result, you may have doubts in its validity.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Isometry" in theorem 1 of [*Liouville*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Liouville) has to be taken *a priori* in the strict sense of your theorem 2 (i.e. an [*affine* transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) preserving distances), not of your final definition, which is that of a [*local* isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry#Manifold).
2. $F=TC$ *itself* is an isometry. Viewed threw the prism of Liouville's theorem, it is the composition of an isometry ($F$), no inversion, and no dilation.
3. Your question is too wide for me but the explanation you *found* on the web for the importance of isometries is fine. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632968).

Comment: Thanks @Anne Bauval. But then why Do Carmo give that "definition" of conformal map in the introduction of the Section 5. Isometries of hyperbolic space; Theorem of Liouville, Chapter VIII, if after take comformal map in another sense?

Comment: I don't think he "after take comformal map in another sense". Btw Moishe Kohan is right: your def is wrong.